# Filter cim instance class by property name

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to filter results by property Name. I **cannot use piping** in my script.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Product -Property Name -Filter "Microsoft*"
```

Returns the error: `Get-CimInstance : Invalid query`.

I'm trying to get output similar to this command:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Product | ? {$_.Name -like 'Microsoft*'}
```

But without piping to `Where-Object`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at `Get-Help Get-CimInstance -Full`, you will find the following -

```
-Filter [<String>]
    Specifies a where clause to use as a filter. Specify the clause in either the WQL or the CQL query language.

    Note: Do not include the where keyword in the value of the parameter.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                none
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

You don't have to include the `Where-Object` here, and you need to write your code as a query. The `-filter` parameter will take the `Property(Name in this case)` in form of the `Windows Query Language`. You don't need to define explicitly mention the `-Property` parameter while making use of the `-filter` parameter. Furthermore, since you are using `WQL`, your wildcard search would change from `*` to `%`, much like that in `SQL`. Keeping these points in mind, you can use the below query -

```
 Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Product -Filter 'Name like "Microsoft%"'
```